# Sum up columns using group by and store as a new column (permanently) in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have 50 columns in the MySQL table. I want to sum all these columns and make a new column into the same table (sum50). 
This should be stored permanently into the MySQL table whenever I update or insert new data. 
I know how to sum up while performing the query but it does not store into the table permanently.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `name` 
AFTER INSERT ON `table` 
FOR EACH ROW  
UPDATE `table` SET `table`.`coulms` =  `table`.`col1`+....      `table`.`col50`+
```

I am trying the above trigger, but not working. 
Should I have a blank column inserted into the table and perform trigger? Which trigger would be correct?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the trigger, add a [generated column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) to your table:

```
alter table tablename add(sum50 int generated always as (col1 + col2 + ...) stored);
```

See a simplified [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/h86mgSmkyd9miqgHnYahqM/0).

Comment: It says unexpected Generated.
Could it be that syntax is different for different versions?

Comment: What is your version of MySql?

Comment: SQL Server: '5.6.24' 
Workbench 6.3

Comment: You are using a very old version of MySql which is now in version 8.0. Generated columns are supported since version 5.7

Comment: Yesss, it's not in my hand to update the version :(